# Rails 5.1.4 and Devise lockable is not displaying error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using `:lockable` from Devise,

The problem I am encountering are these two:

1. The `last_attempt` warning message is never displayed (I am expecting the message to be `"You have one more attempt before your account is locked."` which is in the `devise.en.yml` file as the default)
2. My app is just displays `"Invalid Username or password."` flash message, even if the user is already locked. I am expecting the message to be `"Your account is locked."` which is in the devise.en.yml file as the default

I may be missing something, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

---

Below is my Gemfile snippet:

```
gem 'devise'
gem "devise_ldap_authenticatable", git: "git://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable.git"
gem 'devise_security_extension', git: 'https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension.git', branch: 'master'
```

I am using the devise_security_extension only for its `:session_limitable` module.

Here is my user model snippet:

```
devise :ldap_authenticatable, :registerable, :session_limitable, :timeoutable, :lockable, :trackable, :validatable, authentication_keys: [:username]
```

And here is my devise config snippet:

```
config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts
config.unlock_strategy = :none
config.maximum_attempts = 3
config.last_attempt_warning = true
```

My flash message displayer:

```
- flash.each do |key, value|
  - next if key == "timedout"
  %div{ class: flash_class(key) }
    %button.close{ "aria-hidden": "true", "data-dismiss": "alert", type: "button" } &times;
    = value
```

---

rails is v5.1.4
devise is v4.4.1
devise_ldap_authenticatable is v 0.8.6
devise_security_extension is v0.10.0

---

**UPDATE**
May have something to do with the devise LDAP gem: https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/issues/78
will look into it more

Answer (score 0):

Since in the discussion from https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/issues/78 states that this should be talked/confirmed with the Active Directory side, I will just have to implement my own simple account locking/unlocking.
Will just use the `failed_attempts` column and update the value accordingly.